# Group By records based on start date and end date with count Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose, its May 2017 and I want to get records of April 2017.

My query fetches the record of April 2017 with count but I want to include empty dates as well.

So, a desired output will be like:

```
----------------------
id | date     | count
----------------------
1  | 01/04/17 |  0    // 0 because this dates does not have any tickets.
2  | 02/04/17 |  0    // 0 because this dates does not have any tickets.
3  | 03/04/17 |  0    // 0 because this dates does not have any tickets.
4  | 04/04/17 |  0    // 0 because this dates does not have any tickets.
5  | 05/04/17 |  0    // 0 because this dates does not have any tickets.
6  | 06/04/17 |  0    // 0 because this dates does not have any tickets.
7  | 07/04/17 |  0    // 0 because this dates does not have any tickets.
8  | 08/04/17 |  0    // 0 because this dates does not have any tickets.
```

till `30/04/2017`

`15/04/17` shows 2 count as it contains 2 records and my query does says that as well 
but 
how I can include empty dates as well starting from `01/04/17` - `30/04/2017`

The query is:

```
Ticket.includes(:line_items).where('tickets.created_at > ? AND 
tickets.created_at < ?', Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month, 
Date.today.beginning_of_month).where.not(line_items: {id: nil}).count
```

Output is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "tickets"."id") FROM "tickets" LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"line_items" ON "line_items"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id" WHERE 
(tickets.created_at > '2017-04-01' AND tickets.created_at < '2017-05-01') AND 
("line_items"."id" IS NOT NULL)
```

The desired output should show the record like below:

[image]

Similarly, if user selects for last 7 days, it should show last 7 days records as well.

Any workaround to cope it?

Comment: Is this pgsql or mysql?

Comment: Your question is not clear: do you want the number of tickets created on each day? Why do you have also `line_items`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński its postgres

Comment: @coorasse The `line_items` is used to see if the ticket's line items are present or not. A ticket is considered as final if it contains `line_items` in it. I want to calculate number of tickets for each day of april that contains line_items as well. does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe you are more likely to get answer if you split your question into two - because right now you are looking for someone with knowledge of pgsql and RoR. Your pgsql question is easy to answer and I'm sure that RoR part is as well for someone who has experience coding in it.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Is it easily managable in pgsql? could you please show some attempt or basic idea? Might be it will be easy for me later to make it working for me. The query is written in Rails using pgsql so thing is to cope pgsql for that view. Thats my observation. :)

Comment: Am I right that you want to list, for each day, how many tickets got created with at least one line item?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right in saying that. :) also if no ticket is created in any day it should show `0` against that day but formatting should be the same like I have posted in screenshot. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you stored the user input in a variable named "no_of_days". You could do something like

```
data = Ticket.includes(:line_items).where('tickets.created_at > ? AND tickets.created_at < ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day - (no_of_days).days , Time.now.beginning_of_day).where.not(line_items: {id: nil}) #retrieves all data in a single query

(0..no_of_days).map do |day_from_now|
  todays_data = data.select{|item| item.created_at < (Time.now.beginning_of_day - (day_from_now).days) && item.created_at > (Time.now.beginning_of_day - (day_from_now - 1).days)}
 return { "day": (Date.today - day_from_now.days).strftime("%A %d-%m"), 
  "ticket_count": todays_data.size, 
  "total_sales": todays_data.inject(0){|sum, item| sum + item.line_item.quantity * item.line_item.rate }
end
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could tell more about the user's choices. I was assuming that the user has choices like 
`last week => number of days  = 7`, 
`last month => number of days = 30`, 
`last 2 months => number of days = 60`,
`last year => number of days = 365` 
 and so on.

Comment: Also your code gives me error like: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
  day: Date.today - day_from_now.days, 
      ^
(irb):54: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
  day: Date.today - day_from_now.days, `

Comment: Pardon me for the syntax error. I have updated my answer. This should give something meaningful. I added curly braces to the loop since its returning a hash (key-value pair) for every day. I am only returning days and item_count here. I am not sure about the third column in your screenshot.

Comment: The 2nd column is count of tickets of that particular date. means from my screenshot: `01/04/17 - 2 (tickets in 01/04/17 from ticket table) - $800 (total sales of these 2 tickets means from line_items table: {line_item.count * line_item.quantity}` does that make sense?

Comment: Edited my answer to include total sales. The result would return an array of hashes. You can include that in your view to display tabular data.

Comment: it says: `NameError (undefined local variable or method day_from_now in `data` line. I am looking into it.

Comment: Fixed that. Forgot to change the variable name. Check this now.

Comment: I am getting closer now. I need to ask one thing, is there a way that we can start showing records from lower to upper date? currently its showing from higher to lower date. Any fix? something needs to be changed here: `(Date.today - day_from_now.days).strftime("%A %d-%m")`

Comment: Use this `no_of_days.to_i.downto(0).map do |day_from_now|`

Comment: I have done a lot of coding to improve your answer. I have nearly 25 dropdown options with different criteria in them. I have used your code for start and so going to accept your answer that have provided me right direction. :) The work is still under development for refactoring and wrapping up other options. ;) I will try to post my answer on weekend for your review as well but wouldn't accept it. Stay blessed Mohit and Big thanks as well. Happy Coding Bro. :)

Comment: Great! Thanks! Welcome :) Same to you.

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL-Server* you could achieve in following:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20170401',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20170430';
SELECT t.Id, d.[Date], COALESCE(t.[Count],0) AS [Count]
FROM (
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
) d
LEFT JOIN yourTbl AS t ON d.Date = t.Date
```

Comment: I am using Rails + Postgres. Would that work the same way in rails?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for PostgreSQL, but not for RoR as I don't know it:

```
SELECT dat::date, count(DISTINCT tic."id")
  FROM generate_series('2017-04-01'::date, '2017-04-30'::date, interval '1 day') AS dat
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT "tickets"."id", "tickets"."created_at"
               FROM "tickets"
               JOIN "line_items"
                 ON "line_items"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id") tic
  ON tic."created_at" = dat::date
 GROUP BY dat
 ORDER BY dat
```

or

```
SELECT dat::date, count(DISTINCT "tickets"."id")
  FROM generate_series('2017-04-01'::date, '2017-04-30'::date, interval '1 day') AS dat
  LEFT JOIN "tickets" ON "tickets"."created_at" = dat::date
                     AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "line_items"
                                 WHERE "line_items"."ticket_id" = "tickets"."id" LIMIT 1)
 GROUP BY dat
 ORDER BY dat
```

`generate_series` creates set of rows that goes from `param1` to `param2` with interval at `param3`.